# No mySQL error thrown while trying to UPDATE an empty row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling

Building a small project and trying to learn as I go along.

I get error codes fine if tables are misnamed etc but if I try to UPDATE an empty row I do not get an error. I want to but it isn't telling me I have screwed up. Is this normal?

```
public function updateMessage($id){  //done
    try{
        global $pdo;
        $temp=$this->_message;
        $sql = "UPDATE message SET content=:val  WHERE id=$id";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':val',$temp);
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    { $loc = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $output = "Unable to connect to the database server: $loc <br><h3>Please contact 
    Steve via text on ###### quoting:</h3><h5>" . $e->getMessage() .  "<br>
    Found at $loc.</h5>
    <h3>Thanks. </h3>". "<br>"."<br>" ;
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/beta01/includes/output.html.php";
    exit();
    }
}
```

As I said it works as expected with most errors just not on the empty update problem.

Comment: What exactly is an "*empty row*" and how is it different from any other rows?

Comment: Sorry missed your question. What I meant was if the $id was set to 99 and there was no record with a 99 that was what I meant. Anyhow @dave hit the nail on the head below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "UPDATE message SET content=:val  WHERE id=$id";
```

If it's an "empty row" (assuming I understand you right), then it doesn't meet the condition `WHERE id=$id`, so it worked - it updated the contents of message for every row with that id (there were none).

It sounds like you want to know if no rows were affected by the query, in which case you could do:

```
$s->execute();
if ($s->rowCount() < 1) {
    //throw an exception, show a warning, whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Thanks - good point! I had just done an "affected row == 0" test and did an `INSERT`.

Silly question if I `INSERT` into a row with data I presume I will get an error.